# Rails Devise - changing minimum password length for a particular user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is it possible to have a different devise config for a specific model? I want to have the minimum password length for all user models set to 8 characters, But for Admin model I want to set it to 12 and for another model, say Student, I want to set it to 4. Is that possible?

I tried this:

```
devise :validatable

self.password_length = 4..128
```

inside my student.rb model, but it didn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. No need to set `self.password_length`. We can just do this:

```
devise :validatable, password_length: 8..128
```